# Why cant I display this object in my gridview using Syncfusion Blazor?

Tags: c#, list, gridview, blazor, syncfusion

I'm trying to display a created object of class "FleetDataOverview" into an gridview but it keeps saying "object is not set to an instance of an object", code:

Gridview code:

```
<SfCard ID="">
            <CardHeader Title="Fleet data (24 hours)" />
            <CardContent>
                <SfGrid DataSource="@GridData" AllowPaging="true">
                    <GridColumns>
                        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(FleetDataOverview.FleetId) HeaderText="ID" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120"></GridColumn>
                        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(FleetDataOverview.FleetAverageEEOI) HeaderText=" Average EEOI (CO2 / (cardo * distance sailed))" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120"></GridColumn>
                        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(FleetDataOverview.FleetAverageFOC) HeaderText=" Average FOC (kg/nm)" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120"></GridColumn>
                        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(FleetDataOverview.FleetTotalFuelMass) HeaderText=" Total Fuel Mass (kg)" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120"></GridColumn>
                        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(FleetDataOverview.FleetAverageSpeed) HeaderText=" Average speed (kn)" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120"></GridColumn>
                        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(FleetDataOverview.FleetTotalDistanceSailed) HeaderText=" Total distance sailed (NM)" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120"></GridColumn>
                    </GridColumns>
                </SfGrid>
            </CardContent>
</SfCard>
```

C#:

```
public List<FleetDataOverview> GridData { get; set; }

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    FleetDataOverview averageFleetDataOverView = new FleetDataOverview();
    averageFleetDataOverView.FleetId = "1";
    averageFleetDataOverView.FleetAverageEEOI = "100";
    averageFleetDataOverView.FleetAverageFOC = "200";
    averageFleetDataOverView.FleetTotalFuelMass = "1200";
    averageFleetDataOverView.FleetAverageSpeed = "14";
    averageFleetDataOverView.FleetTotalDistanceSailed = "16000";
    GridData.Add(averageFleetDataOverView);
}

public class FleetDataOverview
{
    public string FleetId { get; set; }
    public string FleetAverageEEOI { get; set; }
    public string FleetAverageFOC { get; set; }
    public string FleetTotalFuelMass { get; set; }
    public string FleetAverageSpeed { get; set; }
    public string FleetTotalDistanceSailed { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code: `public List<FleetDataOverview> GridData { get; set; }`

Should be :

```
 public List<FleetDataOverview> GridData { get; set; } = new List<FleetDataOverview>();
```

Defining a `List<FleetDataOverview>` property still requires you to instantiate the object. Otherwise, the value returns from the get accessor 
is null.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

The reported issue has occurred since your were trying to add objects to list (GridData) whose value is null (it was not initiated). To overcome the reported issue, kindly initialize the GridData as below

```cs
public List<FleetDataOverview> GridData { get; set; } = new List<FleetDataOverview>();
```